# get data from an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I found a php script online that makes it possible to enter subjects and it will make non conflicting schedules from it and it is available here : https://github.com/md100play/university-schedule-generator
however I am facing a problem that I can't get it to display the end time of the class in the time array I uses printr function to print the full array 
it is available here [click here](http://ahrars.com/xa/makeSchedule.php?i=%7B%22allCourses%22%3A%5B%7B%22CourseNum%22%3A%22CT%20113%22%2C%22FOS%22%3A%22ACCT%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22X%22%7D%2C%7B%22CourseNum%22%3A%22CT%20115%22%2C%22FOS%22%3A%22ACCT%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22x%22%7D%2C%7B%22CourseNum%22%3A%22CT%201156%22%2C%22FOS%22%3A%22ACCT%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22XA%22%7D%5D%2C%22timePref%22%3Afalse%2C%22fullClasses%22%3Atrue%2C%22preregistered%22%3A%5B%22%22%5D%2C%22startTime%22%3A%228%3A00%20AM%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%2210%3A00%20PM%22%2C%22unwantedTimes%22%3A%5B%7B%22startTime%22%3A%228%3A00%20AM%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%2210%3A00%20AM%22%7D%5D%7D) I want to be able to print the END time on under the subject's name
any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: you need to show some php & html code

Comment: Please start with reading [mcve] and edit question accordingly.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow please learn https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks guys I will try to edit it to make it better

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of guessing in the code:
If I am right,
You need to print value of ['meetingTime']['Wednesday']['0']['to'] in your output object.

Comment: any idea on how to do that?

Comment: $b = $arr['1493647200']['Wednesday']->meetsFriday->meetingTime;
$b = $b['Wednesday']['0']['to'] ;

Comment: the problem lies in "1493647200" since it is not a constant value it changes for every section

Comment: You can use current() to fetch the first element of the associative array.
Use current($arr), this should give you array with key ['Wednesday'] .